# Why doesn't sympy simplify the Fourier Transform of a derivative?

Tags: python, sympy, continuous-fourier

We know that the Fourier Transform of a derivative is

[image: Fourier transform of a derivative]

where k is the fourier variable.  [Explanation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430858/fourier-transform-of-derivative)

My question is, why doesn't `sympy` use this knowledge? For example:

```
from sympy import Function, symbols, fourier_transform, Derivative

f = Function('f')
x, k= symbols('x, k')

G = fourier_transform(Derivative(f(x), x, x) + f(x), x, k)
print(G)
```

This prints

```
FourierTransform(f(x), x, k) + FourierTransform(Derivative(f(x), x, x), x, k)
```

But I expected it to print (up to some factors of 2 pi i)

```
FourierTransform(f(x), x, k) + k**2 FourierTransform(f(x), x, k)
```

Is there a way to tell `sympy` it's save to make this simplification because I expect f(x) -> 0 as x goes to infinity?

If not, what would be the cleanest way to make the substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple reason Sympy doesn't do this is that [it's not implemented yet](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/integrals/transforms.py#L150). As a workaround for now, you can manually replace the `FourierTransform` of the derivative with a multiplication:

```
from sympy import Wild, FourierTransform, Derivative
a, b, c = symbols('a b c', cls=Wild)
G.replace(
    FourierTransform(Derivative(a, b, b), b, c),
    c**2 * FourierTransform(a, b, c)
)
```

As far as I know, Sympy doesn't offer a pattern that matches an arbitrary number of arguments, so you can't have a single pattern that matches `Derivative(f(x), x)`, `Derivative(f(x), x, x)`, `Derivative(f(x), x, x, x)`, and so on. You could get around that by using the function-function form of `replace()`, but if you know what order of derivative you're dealing with, it's probably simpler to just put in that many `b`s explicitly, as I did in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works, with the slight caveat that replace does not work in-place so I needed an additional `G = ...` (took me longer to figure out than it might seem ;)). Thanks for pointing out that it still needs to be implemented, if I end up using this in my project I might as well submit a PR to implement this.

Comment: Sure, I didn't want to assume whether you wanted to assign the result of the replacement to `G` or not. Sorry I didn't clarify that. If you can properly implement FTs of derivatives I'm sure that would be much appreciated by the Sympy community - but I would imagine the reason it hasn't been done is that it's somehow tricky! So good luck ;-)